# jQuery click function not working with added class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote two jQuery for set and unset button value, also when click on that button 
I pass value to backend using JQuery/Ajax.

```
<a class="btn invite">send invite</a>
```

when click on that link following jQuery is work,

```
   $( ".invite" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "example_1.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#requestFriendShip').html("Request Sent");
                $('#requestFriendShip').removeClass('invite').off('click');
                $('#requestFriendShip').addClass('remove');
            }
        });    
    });
```

then if again click on that change class, I try to follow this jQuery, but this is not working
can someone please give me a solution,

```
$( ".remove" ).click(function() {
    var requestFriendShip =  $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "example_1.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#requestFriendShip').html("Send Invite");
            $('#requestFriendShip').addClass('invite');
            $('#requestFriendShip').removeClass('remove');
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Use `event delegation` http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements